# Aptana autocomplete shows only local stuff

Tags: php, cakephp, ide, aptana

I am trying out Aptana for general PHP development, i loaded an old CakePhp project to test the autocomplete and all i can get are the local functions and variable and absolutely none of the inherited ones, which kinda ruins the whole thing. Is there a setting i dont know about that fixes this?

Comment: It sure would be helpful if you provided step by step for newer users of: "apparently i needed to set up a "Nature" to PHP, the default was some eclipse.something version. Aptana reindexed the file and it works now. " Thanks -John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apparently i needed to set up a "Nature" to PHP, the default was some eclipse.something version. Aptana reindexed the file and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

The original poster was correct in adding PHP to the "Nature" of the project, however he did not provide how to do it. I also had the same problem and once I added PHP to the "Nature" selection list the autocomplete provided the options for inherited classess as well.

To add the PHP Nature:

- Right click on your project in the Project Explorer View
- Click on Properties
- In the "Properties for project" window, select Project Natures in the left list box
- In the Project Natures window, place a tick next to PHP
- Click on OK button

that should get you the autocomplete list.

AJ

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lottttttttttt! The lack of auto completion was really sucking!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used aptana for PHP, but since it's based on Eclipse I assume the `cake` folder (in the same level as your `app` folder usually) needs to be added to your project path.

You can go into the properties of your project and either add it to the path or add it to the libraries.

I usually setup my project to point to the whole folder so I don't need need to do this step, but my Eclipse installation will pick up the inherited methods just fine.

Comment: i do too. My project points to the cakephp folder. app and cake folders both appear on the root level of my project